# MongoDb - InsertCondtion - With Version check - Make Insert only if query has no items

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

I've a repository in which i insert a series of events.

Now i want to make sure that when i insert event dtos that there arent any new events in the meanwhile.

So what i do now is

- Query HighestChangedDate or highest version
- Assert nothing newer (throw if something is newer)
- Make insert

But now between query and insert there is a timegap . I need to group these together so that it is somekind of transactional.

Is there a way to do this or do i have to live with this gap and solve this problem with the infrastructure  ?

Comment: can you do the insert and then the query... so insert the event and then make sure the event you just inserted is the newest in the collection?

Comment: no this doesnt work it should not be persistted at all if there is any newer

Answer (score 1):

I found it out.

I can use FindOneAndUpdate as an Upsert. It is possible to omit the update values and only set the `SetOnInsert` Values
like this

```
  var builder = new UpdateDefinitionBuilder<Dto>();
            var def = builder
                .SetOnInsert(x => x.Version, EventVersion)
```

...

now when running the following update it makes only inserts if my version condition is met

```
collection.FindOneAndUpdate(VersionCondition, updateValues, new FindOneAndUpdateOptions<Event>() {IsUpsert = true});
```

after this i can assert if the document that is returned is the same like i wanted to insert.